# All possibilities of uppercase and lowercase

Tags: string, algorithm, text

I have a task to do here at work which I must test, and I'd like to know if there is a way to show all possibilities of uppercase and lowercase letters within the same word, using some script or any other tool, example:

Word I need to test:

```
en-emea
```

All possibilities of uppercase and lowercase:

```
en-emea
En-Emea
en-eMea
eN-emEa
en-emeA
EN-EMea
en-EmEa
...
```

It could be any programming language, I just need the output text.

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask]

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet, I'm out of ideas how to even try anything with this issue :(

Comment: And what magic language is this supposed to be written in?

Comment: @epascarello any language, i just need the output text

Comment: Does this sequence look familiar?  `0001`, `0010`, `0011`, `0100`, `0101`, `0110`, `0111`, ....  Now what if 0 is lower case and 1 is uppercase?  Is this enough of a hint of how to do what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using permutations with LowerCase and UpperCase

The following example is in Python using recursion:

```
def permute(str):

    if str == '': 
        return ['']

    s = str[:1] #get first letter
    upper = s.upper()
    lower = s.lower()
    permutations = permute(str[1:])

    arr = []
    for item in permutations:
        arr.append(upper + item)
        arr.append(lower + item)

    return arr

results = permute("horse")

print(results)
```